Some links are not showing up under Gazebo's models
I have a .xacro file that is being used to create a urdf to be sent to Gazebo, which is being launched using ROS2. I am trying to update a codebase from ROS to ROS2.
I don't get any errors - I have checked the gazebo logs as well. When i run check_urdf on the compiled urdf - by running xacro [filename], I get
robot name is: pioneer3dx
---------- Successfully Parsed XML ---------------
root Link: base_cover has 1 child(ren)
    child(1):  base_link
        child(1):  front_sonar
        child(2):  p3dx_left_wheel
            child(1):  p3dx_left_hubcap
        child(3):  p3dx_right_wheel
            child(1):  p3dx_right_hubcap
        child(4):  swivel
            child(1):  center_wheel
                child(1):  center_hubcap
        child(5):  top_plate
        child(6):  lms100

However in Gazebo, only the base_cover, swivel and center_wheel show up under LINK - The left and right wheel don't show up in the LINK section, or on the robots
I am using Gazebo classic with Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04
The code can be found on Github since it is quite lengthy - Here
I run the code using ros2 launch udm_pioneer_p3dx main44211.launch.py
Whenever the simulation is run, the colors don't show up, which I am not sure why either, as the old code has the proper colors.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
